# Composite Key validation not working: Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

### **What I tried so far ?**

**My Request class is below**

```
class SubCategoryRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        if(\Auth::user()->RoleID == \App\Enumeration\Role\RoleType::Admin) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];
        $rules['SubCategory'] = 'required|max:25|min:5|unique:tblsubcategory,CategoryID';
        $rules['CategoryID'] = 'required';
        return $rules;
    }

    public function response(array $errors){
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }
}
```

**Below is the Database Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblsubcategory` (
  `SubCategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SubCategory` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `tblsubcategory`
  MODIFY `SubCategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**Below is Unique Key Constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE `tblsubcategory`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SubCategoryID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UK_tblSubCategory_SubCategory_CategoryID` (`CategoryID`,`SubCategory`);
```

**Question**

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **[Reference. As per laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-check-for-unique-column-combanation-from-the-validation-rule?page=1)**

## **Approach #1**

**Go to class `ValidationServiceProvider`, you can find it in below mentioned path.**

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider.php

**Add the below method in this class**

```
public function boot() {
    $this->app['validator']->extend('composite_unique', 
                                 function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        // remove first parameter and assume it is the table name
        $table = array_shift( $parameters ); 

        // start building the conditions
        $fields = [ $attribute => $value ]; 

        // iterates over the other parameters 
        //and build the conditions for all the required fields
        while ( $field = array_shift( $parameters ) ) {
            $fields[ $field ] = \Request::get( $field );
        }

        // query the table with all the conditions
        $result = \DB::table( $table )->select( \DB::raw( 1 ) )->where( $fields )->first();

        return empty( $result ); // edited here
    });
}
```

**Finally the rule will look like below.**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    'SubCategory' => 'required|max:25|min:5|composite_unique:tblsubcategory,CategoryID',
    'CategoryID'  => 'required|min:1'
    ];
}
```

## **Approach #2**

**Rules function has to be like below**

```
public function rules()
{
    // extends Validator only for this request
    \Validator::extend( 'composite_unique', 
                            function ( $attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator ) {

        // remove first parameter and assume it is the table name
        $table = array_shift( $parameters ); 

        // start building the conditions
        $fields = [ $attribute => $value ]; // current field, SubCategory in my case

        // iterates over the other parameters 
        //and build the conditions for all the required fields
        while ( $field = array_shift( $parameters ) ) {
            $fields[ $field ] = $this->get( $field );
        }
        // query the table with all the conditions
        $result = \DB::table( $table )->select( \DB::raw( 1 ) )->where( $fields )->first();

        return empty( $result ); // edited here
    }, 'Category and Sub Category combination already exists' );

    return [
    'SubCategory' => 'required|max:25|min:5|composite_unique:tblsubcategory,CategoryID',
    'CategoryID' => 'required|min:1'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand clearly your problem, but your composite key is CategoryID right? So you want to validate the input fields of CategoryID and SubCategory should not be empty & be UNIQUE when inputting data? Could you post your HTML form?

Anyway, you can try something like this in your Request class:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'txtSubCategory' => 'required|max:25|min:5|unique:tblsubcategory,SubCategory',
        'txtCategoryID' => 'required|unique:tblsubcategory,CategoryID'
    ];
}
```

Then display the message if violate the rules:

```
public function messages () {
    return [
        'txtSubCategory.required'  => 'Sub category name cannot be empty !!',
        'txtSubCategory.unique'    => 'Sub category name is exist !!',
        'txtCategoryID.required' => 'Category ID cannot be empty !!',
        'txtCategoryID.unique'    => 'Category ID is exist !!'
    ];
}
```

Then, your html form must be something like:

```
<form action="" method="">
 <div>
  <label>Sub Category</label>
  <input name="txtSubCategory" placeholder="Please Enter Sub Category" />
 </div>

 <div>
  <label>Category ID</label>
  <input name="txtCategoryID" placeholder="Please Enter Category ID" />
 </div>
</form>
```

And use this to display errors message in your html page:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)  
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Unique key is combination of two columns. `CategoryID` and `SubCategory`

Comment: What ever it is... your problem is validation, isn't it..? So you should post your html page instead of a database schema, because the validation works for html fields, not for validating .. a database!!!

Comment: unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. Your post says validation about individual Columns. Whereas my problem is based on Composite Key. Anyways. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: lol, as the title said, it is about composite key VALIDATION NOT WORKING